# Shorten resx file WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a background image in a WinForm. On the resx file the base64 image occupies 30 thousand lines with 3.4 MB size. How can I shrink it or make it reference an image without converting it into a long string?

```
<data name="$this.BackgroundImage" type="System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64">
    <value>
            iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAADwAAAAkuCAYAAAAATalBAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAA/8dJREFUeF7s.....
     ...AP/gAAH/4AAH/+AGf//gB///4Af///////8=
    </value>
```

Comment: Can you not save the image in a folder somewhere in your project and just reference it? That would be way better than having the base64 string in the code itself.

Comment: When you select the background image in the designer, choose "Project resource file" instead of "Local resource": https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RQR8.png

Comment: I did import it from Project Resources but the adress is still 3.4MB